# Why am I receiving this Invalid Hooks Call error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am trying to create a function that is called when you click add to cart on a product page. This function is in a separate file and is imported to the product page and is called onClick. However, I receive this error that says Invalid Hooks Call. What am I doing wrong?

````
import {AuthContext} from '../context/auth'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import {Button} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import {useMutation} from '@apollo/react-hooks'

const AddtoCart = (id) => {
    console.log(id)                                         //id gets logged into the console here. 
    
    const [errors,setErrors] = useState({})                 ////shows error right here <<
   
    const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);                 
    const[addtoCart,{loading}] = useMutation(ADDTOCART,{
        update(_,result){
            //TODO: remove this alert
            
            alert('success')
        },
        onError(err){
           alert('error')
            
        },
        variables:{
            productID:id
        }

    })
    if(user){
        addtoCart(id)
    }
    else{
      if(localStorage.getItem('cart')){
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        cart.unshift(id);
        localStorage.removeItem('cart');    
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));

      }else{
          var cart = [id];
          localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
      }

    }
   
}


const ADDTOCART = gql`
    mutation addtoCart($productID: ID!){
        addtoCart(productID: $productID)
    }


`

export default AddtoCart;```
````

Comment: Did you import `React` and `useState` ?

Comment: Simply put, you are breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). React hooks are only valid in React functional components and other custom hooks, they also cannot be called in loops, conditionally, or in callbacks, which it appears `AddtoCart` is a callback function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are exporting `AddToCart` and calling that from the `onClick`? This will not work because `useState` is being called from the wrong context. The difference is that this function isn't a React component itself. Calling the function inside of a React component isn't sufficient, hook calls need to happen either in a custom hook (called in a component) or in a component.

If you want to have the function you're using modify state, then you can pass the `setErrors` function to it as an argument, and have the call to `useState` inside of the component that renders the button. You should do the same thing with the `useMutation` and `useContext`.

I would recommend lifting the hooks into the wrapping component, and just pass `user` to the related logic:

```
function addToCart(user, id) {
  if(user){
    addtoCart(id)
  }
  else {
    if(localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
      cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
      cart.unshift(id);
      localStorage.removeItem('cart');    
      localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    } 
    else {
      var cart = [id];
      localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    }
  }
}
```

This function could be called in the `onClick` so long as you move the hooks calls into the scope of the container

I definitely recommend giving [the rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation) a read. It does a better job than me explaining why you can't have a hook in a nested function.